# Cannot click input[type=radio] after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i load content with ajax, but after that i cannot click on input type radio.

I have read a lot and i changed it to that jQuery Code. But nothing happens..

Can anybody help me?

```
$('#content').on('click change', 'input[type=radio]', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    $('#bet').fadeIn(300);


    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var tip = $(this).data('tip');
    var team = $(this).data('team');
    var quote = $(this).data('quote');
    var earnings = 0;
    var amount = $('#stake').val();
});
```

Thats the Ajax Call

```
$.get('http://localhost/..../getGames?cat_id=' + cat_id, function(data){
        $('#content table.ui.table tbody').empty();
        $.each(data, function(index, gameObj){

            $('#content table.ui.table tbody')
                    .append('<tr><td>'+ gameObj.team1.name +'</td><td>'+ gameObj.team2.name +'</td><td>'
                    + '<div class="inline fields"><div class="field"><div class="ui radio checkbox">'
                    + '<input type="radio" name="game" data-id="'+ gameObj.id +'" data-team="'+ gameObj.team1.name +'" data-tip="1" data-quote="'+ gameObj.quote_1 +'">'
                    + '<label>'+ gameObj.quote_1 +'</label></div></div>'
                    + '<div class="field"><div class="ui radio checkbox">'
                    + quote_0 
                    + '<a href="">test</a>'
                    + '<div class="field"><div class="ui radio checkbox">'
                    + '<input type="radio" name="game" data-id="'+ gameObj.id +'" data-team="'+ gameObj.team2.name +'"  data-tip="2" data-quote="'+ gameObj.quote_2 +'">'
                    + '<label>'+ gameObj.quote_2 +'</label></div></div></div>'
                    + '<td>'+ gameObj.start_at +'</td></tr>');
           //console.log(subcatObj.id);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Do you have a snippet of what code is returned from the ajax call? Is it possible that it's not populated yet? Need to see where you have that on call.

Comment: i have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think nothing wrong with the code. The issue you are seeing may be with having the line:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Thank you, but also without event.preventDefault(); nothing happens.. it´s mysterios :/

Comment: I dont know why... but it´s not working with input[type=radio] .. i have changed to a `<a data-id="'+ gameObj.id +'" data-team="'+ gameObj.team1.name +'" data-tip="1" data-quote="'+ gameObj.quote_1 +'">'
                        + '<label>'+ gameObj.quote_1 +'</a>` and with '<a>' Element it´s working.